# How to use ssh host rm -rf path to delete the files?

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to use `ssh host rm -rf` to delete the file , but when I use `ssh host rm -rf /disk/directory/*` the result show

```
ssh: No match.
```

What is the problem ?

thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You glob pattern `*` is expanded by the local shell before being passed to `ssh`.

You need to pass it on to `ssh`.  Use quotes:

```
ssh host "rm -rf /disk/directory/*"
```

Answer (score 1):

The "*" is expanded on your local machine's command line before being transmitted. The easiest fix should be:

```
ssh host rm -rf /disk/directory/
```